# Maximize use of Vcores by Yarn when running spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have a virtualized cluster with Hadoop 2.9 in 4 nodes.
Each node it has 16 cpu's with 126 gb ram.

For more that i try to set yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores to something different than 1, when i run spark-submit declaring yarn as master, it uses only 1 vcore for each container.

Is there a way to override that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `spark.executor.cores`. From [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#execution-behavior):

> The number of cores to use on each executor. In standalone and Mesos coarse-grained modes, setting this parameter allows an application to run multiple executors on the same worker, provided that there are enough cores on that worker. Otherwise, only one executor per application will run on each worker.

which by default is:

> 1 in YARN mode